# Convert numerical ticks to their textual meaning in BubbleChart

Tags: plotting

In my dataset (see below), the months are represented by a numerical variable.  However, in my `BubbleChart` plot, I would like to have them represented by their name.  How do I change the ticks on the horizontal axis to represent the months?

```
BubbleChart[
  GhanaMalariaData[[All, {3, 4, 8}]], 
  ChartLabels -> GhanaMalariaData[[All, 4]], 
  ChartStyle -> 24, ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Dashed], 
  ChartElements -> \!(* Graphics3DBox[SphereBox[{0, 0, 0}], 
  Boxed->False, ImageSize->30, Lighting->"Neutral", 
  ViewPoint->{0, DirectedInfinity[-1], 0}]), Frame -> True
]
```

[image]

---

Here is a sample from the dataset:

```
8.47    -0.01   3   2002    3   2002    9   39  70
9.4063  -0.99   2   2002    2   2002    9   34  69
6.7 -1.634  10  2002    2   2003    5   8   189
5.704   0.101   7   1993    7   1993    15  115 354
5.583   -0.21   10  2002    1   2003    4   40  219
6.695   -1.64   10  2002    2   2003    5   5   145
9.6444  -1.02   2   2002    2   2002    9   29  71
9.7036  -0.99   3   2002    3   2002    9   47  71
```

Comment: ...and where is your dataset?

Comment: It is in a variable called Ghanadata.  It has latitude, longitude, strating month (a numerical variable), starting year, ending month, ending year,  and positive patients.  All the variables are numerical

Comment: @user34018 could you add the code that generated the BubbleChart you show above as well? Also, you mention seven variable types in your comment above, but your data contains nine columns. What is the rest of the data?

Comment: Here is the code : BubbleChart[GhanaMalariaData[[All, {3, 4, 8}]], 
 ChartLabels -> GhanaMalariaData[[All, 4]], ChartStyle -> 24, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Dashed], ChartElements -> \!\(\*
Graphics3DBox[SphereBox[{0, 0, 0}],
Boxed->False,
ImageSize->30,
Lighting->"Neutral",
ViewPoint->{0, 
DirectedInfinity[-1], 0}]\), Frame -> True]  the last column is called examined, or the number of patients examined to see if the have malaria

Answer (score 1):

Generate a series of labels for your ticks (rotated to run vertically, so they won't overlap when in the plot):

```
monthticks = Transpose@{
   Range[12], 
   Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
     "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
  };
```

Use those ticks in a custom `FrameTicks` specification:

```
BubbleChart[GhanaMalariaData[[All, {3, 4, 8}]],
  ChartLabels -> GhanaMalariaData[[All, 4]],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {monthticks, None}}
]
```

[image: bubble chart]

Comment: @user34018 you are very welcome, glad to help!